# DS-160- Countries visited after filing DS160

Tags: usa, schengen, visa-refusals, h1b-visas

I have filed the DS 160 and booked an appointment for H1B visa stamping. I am currently in the US. My status is transferred to H1B from F1 and I'll be going to India for stamping.
While filing DS160, I have added US in the countries visited in last 5 years.

Now I have made a plan to visit the Europe while going to India for stamping. I got Schengen visa for 1 week in Germany.
Is there going to be any problem as in DS160, I have not mentioned about it, as it was not planned before while filing DS160.
Do I need to file another DS160 and take new appointment?

Answer (score 4):

The form is filled to the best of your knowledge as of the time of the submission. The countries visited in the last five years will get updated, let's say, when you go for your visa extension. So it can be accounted for and tracked.

When you go to the interview, your passport will have the schengen visa stamp. At most they may ask you how you didn't declare this. Your honest answer is that as of the time of submission of the DS-160 form you didn't even have it on your itinerary and didn't know if the schengen would be granted.

*Some questions are just to gather additional traveler profile. Say, if you show that you have traveled a lot, then it will seem to the Visa officer that you have already 'made the cut' and have been looked at from a security perspective by multiple countries. So it builds confidence. (Not to say if you haven't it is a bad thing.)*

**That said, you should also contact your legal team that is filing your H1B. The company pays them to represent and consult for you. They may know of some reasons why you may have to amend the DS-160.**